# Router Rate Limiting when connecting to local network via WAN Interface

Tags: networking

I am setting up a home server using port forwarding and dyndns. I have port forwarded HTTP port 80 from my WAN IP (47.x.x.x) to my Local IP(192.168.254.101)

The problem here is that whenever I try to curl my WAN IP (47.x.x.x) on port 80 from one of my PC in the same network (192.168.254.100) connected to same router, there appears to be some kind of rate limiting going on. It works for the first time but hangs on successive ones. If I wait for a while, it works again for the first time and hangs second time and so on.

However, when I do the same curl to same WAN IP (47.x.x.x) from a different PC that is not in my local network, the curl works just fine. I can even hit it consecutive number of times and it does not hang. It also works when I'm connected to VPN in my local PC (192.168.254.100).

If anyone has any idea what is happening, please let me know.

Comment: I'd think it could be related with [NAT hairpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) (which somehow would misbehave). But I have no idea how to check for this.

Comment: Use the local IP on the Lan.  If you want to pretend that you are outside the firewall from inside the firewall and have everything play nice, you need to know a lot more than you do about NAT and routing and we need to know a lot more about your environment.  "Why" you want to do this is an important question.  Your answer would define what you should do.